# Windows version of x-forwarding

Tags: windows, remote-access, remoteapp

I am working on an application that displays remote applications on a local machine. On Linux, this is done by creating a custom x server on the host and forwarding the TCP packets to the client.

I would very much like to make this work with Windows, and supporting access through any modern browser is a future goal. This means that any communication must be able to work over a network connection.

I am looking for a UDP, TCP, or HTTP API. I control the host, so I can install any software necessary there. If there is no network API, then I can create one.

Is there an open API for forwarding drawing of an application to a remote client? (like [this](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/xproto/x11protocol.html#requests:CreateGC) for X)

I found [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730673(WS.10).aspx), but it doesn't seem to provide an API for creating my own TS Web Access-like client.

Note:

I've heard about Cisco's products, as well as VMWare's, and I know about the different remote desktop applications available for Windows. These are not what I'm looking for. I am looking for an API where I could implement the drawing on a remote machine (I don't want the whole desktop, only the application).

I would also like a complete package (mouse and keyboard events).

Answer (score 1):

Terminal Services with RDP (Remote Desktop) can already do most of this.  Remote Desktop is more than just Microsoft's version of VNC, and is closer to how linux does the X server/client.  Unfortunately, this will fail your "any modern browser" requirement, as the TSWeb ActiveX component is IE-only.

Comment: There are RDP clients for linuxes.

Comment: Does it have an API that I can build off of? This is what I'm really looking for. I'd like to get the raw network stream and handle my own drawing, if possible.